# Implementing synchronization barriers

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, barrier

On this website http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4410/2010fa/synchreview.pdf it says that implementing a barrier for multiple iterations must be implemented in the following way:

```
class Barrier:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.incount = 0
        self.outcount = 0
        self.N = N
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.everyoneatbarrier = Condition(self.lock)

    def barrier(self, processid):
        with self.lock:
            self.incount += 1
            if self.incount == self.N
                self.everoneatbarrier.notifyAll()
            while self.incount < self.N or 
                (self.incount >= self.N and self.outcount < self.N):
                self.everyoneatbarrier.wait()
            self.outcount += 1
            if self.outcount == self.N:
                self.outcount = 0
                self.incount ­= self.N
```

Wouldn't it be simpler if we just used a simple if-else statement like:

```
    def barrier(self, processid):
        with self.lock:
            self.count += 1
            if self.count == self.N :
                self.everyoneatbarrier.notifyAll()
            else :
                self.everyoneatbarrier.wait()
            self.count = 0
```

I don't understand all the extra effort. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The extra effort in the example is due to maintain the associated state to the behaviour of a cyclic barrier (it can be reused after all waiting threads are released).

In your simplification I think there are two problems, it´s not reusable and you are not protecting the wait call against spurious wakeups:

```
  def barrier(self, processid):
    with self.lock:
        self.count += 1
        if self.count == self.N :
            self.everyoneatbarrier.notifyAll()
        else :
            while self.count < N:
                self.everyoneatbarrier.wait()
```